# how to pass parameters in return url and get back them to callee page on return

Tags: apex, visualforce, url

I was sending parameters in return url in

```
 pagereference ref=new PageReference('/ui/content/ViewAllAttachmentsPage?id='+id+'&retURL=/apex/CustomTicketsave?id='+id+'&se='+se+'&idValEntr='+idValEntr+'&currentURL='+oldURL1);
```

after doing some actions on standard attachments page i want to return back to callee page along with paramaters like the url needed is

```
 https://c.cs17.visual.force.com/apex/CustomTicketsave?id=500g000000CauQ9AAJ&se=&idValEntr=&currentURL=/apex/UnclaimedTicketPage
```

but it is returning just url without parameters..

```
  https://c.cs17.visual.force.com/apex/CustomTicketsave?id=500g000000CauQ9AAJ
```

but to do some operations on callee page i need parameters on return url..

I was just looking, is there any way to get the parameters in return url..

Seems to be it's taking only one parameter along url but its not considering remaining parameters appended using & operator

Answer (score 2):

i have over come this using page-reference members

```
string retURL='/apex/CustomTicketsave?id='+id+'&se='+se+'&idValEntr='+idValEntr+'&currentURL='+oldURL1;
        pagereference ref=new PageReference('/ui/content/ViewAllAttachmentsPage');
        ref.getParameters().put('id', id);
        ref.getParameters().put('retURL', retURL);
         return ref;
```

this is working fine...